# Git gui blame from Sublime Text 3

Tags: git, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I have tried many things, but none of them worked.

**Expected result:** I type a shortkey, and git gui blame opens the current file at the line the pointer is on.

I work on Windows 7, with Sublime 3 Build 3083

### First try : Custom Build System

```
{ "cmd": [ "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\cmd\\git.exe" "gui" "blame" "$file"] }
```

In a file named git_gui_blame.sublime-build

Then Tools -> Build System -> git_gui_blame.
But then Ctrl+B only makes "no build system" appear [image: image showing the error]

### Second try : Custom key binding

Preference -> Key Bindings - User

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+B"],
  "command": "exec", 
  "args": { 
            "cmd": [
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\cmd\\git.exe",
                "gui",
                "blame",
                ?//What to put here ?
                ]
          } 
},
```

I tried replacing "?" with "$file", inspired from the $file of the build system, but I got this error
[image: incorrect_file_path]

which can be translated by "Incorrect file path : /path/to/$file : Inexistant file or repertory

### Third try : Custom Plugin

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin, os

class SublimeBlameCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
def run(self, **kwargs):
    folder_name, file_name = os.path.split(self.window.active_view().file_name())
    print(folder_name + " _______ " + file_name)
    try:
        self.window.active_view().run_command('exec', {'cmd': ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\cmd\\git.exe', 'gui', 'blame', file_name], 'working_dir':folder_name, 'shell':False} )
    except TypeError:
        print("Error in SublimeBlame Plugin")
```

and after that, in Preferences -> Key Bindings - User

```
  { "keys": ["ctrl+k"], 
  "command": "sublime_blame"
  },
```

But Ctrl+k does absolutely nothing.

So I'm stuck here. What can I do differently ?
My prefered try is the second because I feel I got the closest to the expected result, but I couldn't find what to replace the "?" with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working with:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin, subprocess, os, ntpath

class GitguiblameCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):    def run(self,
edit):
    if os.name == "nt":
        startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
        startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW

    filepath = self.view.file_name()
    dirpath = os.path.dirname(filepath)
    filename = ntpath.basename(filepath)
    process = subprocess.Popen(('C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.cmd', 'gui', 'blame', filename),cwd=os.path.dirname(filepath),
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, startupinfo=startupinfo)
```

It seems git-gui appends filename to currentworking directory. Use os.path.split or os.path.basename on other OS's.